# False Positives outside date range in this mySQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I am getting historical count data together in an automated report.  The two main tables schemas are below.  The third table referenced is `person` which has it's ids as foreign keys in `email_list_subscription`.  That table's primary key consists of the two foreign keys `email_list` and `person`.

[SQLFIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a8ad/1/0)

The query below is coming up with a count which is outside the date ranges allowed in the query and I can't figure out why.  It has rows for an email list that definitely has now rows in 2014 at all.

```
CREATE TABLE `email_list` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `handle` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operator` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operator_contact_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operator_contact_email` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operator_contact_phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operator_listid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `handle` (`handle`),
  KEY `handle_2` (`handle`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `email_list_subscription` (
  `email_list` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `person` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `as_email_address` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime_synced_to_operator` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `opted_in` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `opted_out` datetime NOT NULL,
  `undeliverable` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email_list`,`person`),
  KEY `email_list` (`email_list`),
  KEY `person` (`person`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is a query dumped from the script and it's results checked directly in mySQL monitor:

```
SELECT 
  el.id, el.handle, 
  els.`email_list` , 
  COUNT( els.person ) AS c 
FROM 
  `email_list` el, 
  `email_list_subscription` els 
WHERE 
  el.id = els.email_list 
  AND (
    DATE( els.`datetime_synced_to_operator` ) >= '2014-04-01' 
    OR 
    DATE( els.`opted_in` ) >= '2014-04-01'
  ) 
  AND (
    DATE( els.`datetime_synced_to_operator` ) <= '2014-05-18' 
    OR 
    DATE( els.`opted_in` ) <= '2014-05-18'
  ) 
GROUP BY els.`email_list`
```

How is this capturing `els` rows whose dates are not in the range?

Comment: Can you post some sample data or make a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `DATE()` calls are going to kill your performance, much better to do

```
els.`datetime_synced_to_operator` >= '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
```

(for example).

Also, it is not clear your date ranges are going to work as intended; this seems more clear (but may have different results depending on data):

```
WHERE el.id = els.email_list 
   AND (
         ( els.`datetime_synced_to_operator` BETWEEN '2014-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-05-18 23:59:59')
         OR 
         ( els.`opted_in` BETWEEN  '2014-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-05-18 23:59:59')
       )
;
```

**Also: What was wrong with the original where (below)?**

```
AND (
    DATE( els.`datetime_synced_to_operator` ) >= '2014-04-01' 
    OR 
    DATE( els.`opted_in` ) >= '2014-04-01'
  ) 
  AND (
    DATE( els.`datetime_synced_to_operator` ) <= '2014-05-18' 
    OR 
    DATE( els.`opted_in` ) <= '2014-05-18'
  )
```

Best illustrated with an example... any row with `datetime_synced_to_operator` any time after the start date (even after the end date) and an `opted_in` any time before the end date (even before the start date) gives true for this clause; and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you, this does produce the results I expect but I am confused as to what was done incorrectly with the ranges?  I appreciate the advice on DATE() too!  I use it a lot and did not realize it was expensive.

Comment: Re: `DATE()`, the function itself is not that expensive, that advice goes for using any function on a field in the source tables; doing so requires MySQL do a full table scan, evaluating the function for every row, instead of taking advantage of indexes on the field. (Editing the answer for what was "wrong" with your range logic.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I wish I'd had the problem and explanation sooner!